# Проблема со страницами сайта на WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, seo

Есть некоторая страница:

**mysite.com/page**

Она отлично работает.
Но, если к ней дописать какой-то набор цифр, к примеру:

**mysite.com/page/1111**

То отправляет не на 404 страницу, а открывается страница **/page** с урлом **/page/1111**. С точки зрения СЕО это будет дубль страницы.

Если прописать не цифры, а просто набор символов, то будет переправлять на страницу 404.

Если страница типа:

**mysite.com/blog/category/**

То при добавлении цифр все работает как нужно - перенаправляет на страницу 404.

Перенес сайт на локалку, чтоб провесты тесты, а там такого нет, все работает как нужно. Файл  .htaccess с такими же правилами.

Может кто-то знает как решить это? Может реврайт прописать какой-то?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

При правильной настройке WP должен перенаправлять `mysite.com/page/1111` на `mysite.com/page/`.

Это не баг, а фича. Цифры после имени страницы - для пагинации внутри страницы. Для SEO это никакой не дубль, хотя бы потому, что на сайте у вас нет такой ссылки `mysite.com/page/1111`, поэтому поисковик туда никак не попадёт.

Кроме того, все поисковики прекрасно отслеживают редиректы. Не надо считать их дурнее паровоза.

Comment: Тут ты не прав. ПО деволту нет редирктов со страниц и постов. Есть только костыль - каноникал. Редирект появляется при использовании сео-плагинов с настройкой запрета индексации пагинации. Что тоже сомнительное решение.

Comment: Да перестань. Специально проверил на ядре без плагинов - есть переадресация с `/page/111` на `/page/`.

Comment: Поставь голый ВП и проверь. И да "/page/111" - редиректов не будет, а "/mypage/111" - будет.

Comment: Да, есть другое поведение для страницы с именем page, отличное от всех остальных. Но вряд ли ТС имел ввиду именно такой слаг. Он говорил о некой странице. А на ВСЕХ страницах, кроме страницы со слагом /page есть редирект

Comment: Вот именно, что у ТСа не такой слаг и поэтому никакого редиректа у него не должно быть (по дефолту). (Я вчера в предыдущем комменте запарился - редиректа нигде нет. Но есть отличие в том ***что*** выдавать)

Answer (score 1):

Это не баг, это фича ВП. (задокументированный баг является фичей (с) :) ). Но если не поломать каноникал, то он там прописан правильно и проблем с ПСами нет (почти нет ;))