# Почему нет редиректа в WordPress. если добавить к ссылке /0

Tags: wordpress

Для примера https://wordpress.org/download/0/

Разве не должно быть 404 или редиректа?

Comment: Это не баг, это фича https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1440815/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-wordpress/1440873#1440873

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.